# How to stop end=' ' from putting the next line on the previous line

Tags: python-3.x

I have been given a task to basicly import a text file to a dictionary and then let the user input words to translate from English to an Indigeonous language. This is what i have so far, but when i want to re-ask words to translate, it puts the input question on the previous answer line. I have done all of the translation bits, i just need help with the printing part.

```
lan = {}
for line in open('dictionary.txt'):
  en, ab = line.rstrip().split(",")
  lan[en] = ab
req = input('English: ')
while req:
  words = req.split()
  for i in range(len(words)):
    print(lan[words[i]], end=' ')
  req = input('English: ')
```

I get this:

```
English: I like python
ngaju kuja-piya malilyi English:
```

But i want to get this:

```
English: I like python
ngaju kuja-piya malilyi
English:
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either put a blank print statement before you ask for input like so:

```
    for i in range(len(words)):
        print(lan[words[i]], end=' ')
    print()
    req = input('English: ')
```

or just put a newline character before your input statement like so:

```
    for i in range(len(words)):
        print(lan[words[i]], end=' ')
    req = input('\nEnglish: ')
```